# Наследование метода в c#

Tags: c#, классы, наследование

Доброго всем времени суток.
Возник вопрос ,связанный с наследованием методов. 
Есть 2 класса:

```
        public class Student
        {
            protected private String Name { get; set; }
            public Student(String Name)
            {
                this.Name = Name;
            }
            public void GetCourse(String Course)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Course);
            }
        }
```

```
        public class Worker : Student
        {
            protected private String Course { get; set; }
            public Worker(String Name,String Course):base(Name)
            {
                this.Course = Course;
            }
            public void GetCourse()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Course);
            }
        }
```

Возможно ли сделать у класса Worker наследование метода `GetCourse(String Course)` ,где вместо параметра `String Course` будет участвовать поле `protected private String Course { get; set; }` .А сам метод будет вызываться как :

```
Worker A = new Worker("Name","Course");
A.GetCourse();
```

Или же необходимо создать новый метод, как в описании второго класса?

Comment: 1) Нет такой вещи, как наследование методов. Есть переорпделение методов, есть скрытие методов. Наследования нет. 2) Методы с разным количествои параметров являются разными методами. Вы не можете переопределять или скрывать метод, создавая другой метод с другим количеством параметров.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо огромное))))

Comment: Вот ненмного [инфы про сигнатуры методов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods#method-signatures)

Comment: @tym32167 Еще раз спасибо,буду учиться))

Comment: @tym32167 А в случае сокрытия метода можно ли полностью его убрать из класса-наследника?Если да,то как это сделать?

Comment: Помимо того, о чём вам @tym32167 сказал. Конструктор класса - плохое место чтобы назначить курс студенту, это примерно как пожизненное рабство: только человек родился а вы ему назначили место работы до гробовой доски. Логичнее смотрится метод AssignCourse(string courseName). И если вам не подходит сигнатура базового метода - то вам надо сразу задуматься, почему бы её так и не написать как в базовом классе? Зачем переопределять? Кроме того, наследование должно быть обоснованным, вы же розу наследуете от цветов, а не от тараканов? А работник почему от студента?

Comment: @AK Это исключительно упрощенный пример, чтобы не сбивать с толку лишним кодом, а получить ответ на конкретный вопрос)))А с фантазией всегда было плохо))

Comment: Так у вас в примере логика хромает, я отчего-то подозреваю, что в реальном приложении ещё запутаннее. Потому что вы одной рукой наследуете, другой рукой хотите сделать вещи, ломающие наследование. И какой бы пример вы не подобрали -- вопрос именно об этом "Как бы мне отнаследоваться, чтобы не наследоваться" и проблемуэту не замечаете, типа "дайте мне просто ответ".

Comment: И при сокрытии и при переопределении вы по сути заменяете один метод другим. Потому в C# нельзя убрать метод из класса родителя, можно только подменить его другим методом с той же сигрантурой. Подробнее [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.42.php) и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)

Comment: Курс назначается студенту, но метода назначения нет. Есть метод Dump, даже не Get. При этом наследник назначает через конструктор курс - и вы хотите чтобы в потомке Dump использовал логику назначения в базовом классе, но там этого нет. Окей, почему вы не хотите сохранить в потомке этот курс и в потомке его Dump'ить? Вы не видите противоречия и того, что вы упорно идёте дорогами которые ведут в разных направлениях? Либо работа с курсом в базовом классе есть, либо её нет, но тогда уж по-честному: нет и не будем просить из базового класса, раз её там нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`protected` и `private` не совместимы, это разные модификаторы доступа, либо одно, либо другое. Все равно, что написать `public private`. И тип `string` с маленькой буквы, как и любой другой базовый тип!

A K прав, создание методов-пустышек могут позволить себе только `abstract class`(абстрактные классы), но никак не самостоятельные. А ситуация с `GetCourse()` решается просто, с помощью методов доступа поля, а не функцией.

```
public class Human {

    // поле публичное, но присваивается только в классе Human (private)
    // если указать protected вместо private можно было бы присваивать и в дорчерних классах, но в данном контексте это не имеет смысла
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get { return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Subtract(BirthDate).Ticks).Year-1; } }
    
    public Human (string name, DateTime birthDate) {
        Name = name;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Student : Human {

    public string EducationCourse { get; private set; }

    public Student (string name, DateTime birthDate, string course) : base(name, birthDate) {
        EducationCourse = course;
    }

    // делаем из человека, студента
    public Student (Human human, string course) : this(human.Name, human.BirthDate, course) { }
}
```

---

```
public class Worker : Student {

    public string Profession { get; private set; }

    public Worker (string name, DateTime birthDate, string profession, string course = "") : base(name, birthDate, course) {
        Profession = profession;
    }

    // делаем из человека, работника, у которого возможно нет образования
    public Worker (Human human, string profession, string course = "") : this(human.Name, human.BirthDate, course, profession) { }

    // делаем из студента, работника
    public Worker (Student student, string profession) : this(student.Name, student.BirthDate, student.EducationCourse, profession) { }
}
```

Но то, что `Human`, `Student` и `Worker` разные классы это странно. Получается, что безработный не может иметь образования, а студент не может быть работником.